# What means: "Factor out the GCF of each binomial" solving a algebraic equations with AC Method.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning, factoring

I already solved various exercises using AC method but I am having problem for understand what means **"Factor out the GCF of each binomial"**

This is what I did the the function is:

$F(x) = x^2 + 16x +63 $

step1: Multiply $ 1\cdot63 = 63 $

step2: Find two factor of 63 whose sum equals the coefficient of the middle term, which is 16.

step 3: Rewrite original trinomial:

$  x^2 + 16x +63 $

Separating we have (1) and (2):

(1) $x² + 9x$ (2) $7x + 63$

(1) $x(x + 9)$ (2) $7(x + 9)$

(1) with (2) The Result is:

$ (x+7)(x+9) $

I know what means **Split the linear term of the function, writing  as the sum of two binomials** and **factoring by grouping.**

**The answer of the book of Factor out the GCF of each binomial is:**

$x\left(x+7\right)+9\left(x+7\right)$

Comment: Presumably "*GCF*" means "*greatest common factor*", and "*factor out the GCF of each binomial*" refers to this step $\,\left(x^2+9x\right)+\left(7x+63\right)=x(x+9)+7(x+9)\,$. Taking the first one, for example, $\,x^2+9x\,$ is a binomial and the GCF of its terms is $\,\gcd(x^2,9x)=x\,$, so you factor that out and get $\,x^2+9x=x(x+9)\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolution is correct. you only modified the way that you take the factors of sum in (1) and (2).

$ x^2 + 16x +63 $

(1) $x² + 7x$ (2) $9x + 63$

(1) $x(x + 7)$ (2) $9(x + 7)$

so we have:
$x(x + 7)+ 9(x + 7)$ # This is the Factor out the GCF of each binomial

(1) with (2) The Result is:

$ (x+9)(x+7) $